# O que é Ansi Escape Code?

Tags: c, terminal, ansi

Para a manipulação de do terminal do linux *(console de outros SO também)*, é usando uma sequencia de caracteres iniciado com um valor em hexadecimal **0x1B** conhecida como *ANSI Escape Code*.

Como por exemplo `printf("\x1B[32mMy Text\n")`.

Como funciona o *ASNI Escape Code*?

O que ele é Exatamente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## ANSI Escape Code

Existe um padrão feito baseado em uma norma ***[ANSI](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_National_Standards_Institute)*** para controlar as saídas feitas em um terminal de texto.

A manipulação dessas saídas são feitas por comandos chamados *ANSI Escape Codes*, que são ativados pelo caractere de valor **27** ou **1B** em hexadecimal (Botão Esc) seguido de **[** (abre colchete), após isso, é passado um valor e uma letra para representar sua ação.

## Exemplos

Para posicionar o cursor em uma determinada posição da tela, usa-se as letras **H** ou **f**, passando junto a linha e a coluna para o cursor.

```
printf("\x1B[%d;%dH",6, 5);
printf("\x1B[%d;%df",6, 5);
```

Para limpar a tela, usa-se o valor **2** seguido do caractere **J**.

```
printf("\x1B[2J");
```

Para mudar a cor do texto a ser escrito, usa-se o valor da cor seguido de **m**.

```
printf("\x1B[31mRed"); // Escreve em vermelho
printf("\x1B[01;32mBoldGreen"); // Escreve em verde e negrito
printf("\x1B[00mTexto Normal"); // Retira estilo
```